# How to give preference to non-expired posts in union

Tags: mysql

The "offer" type expires with 1 or 0, the "Sweep" type expires by expiration date. How can I give them more weight in the query when they re not expired?

The current query (for the search page):

```
    SELECT 
    'offer' AS type,
    id,
    expired, 
    title,
    description,
    header,
    slug,
    date_original,
    date 
FROM cs_offers 
WHERE MATCH(title,title,description,keywords,header,country,offer_description) AGAINST ('$search_main' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

    UNION 

SELECT 
    'sweep' AS type,
    id,
    title,
    description,
    header,
    expire_date,
    slug,
    date_original, 
    date_original AS date
FROM cs_sweeps
WHERE MATCH(title,title,description,keywords,header,category,location,entry_type,country,w) AGAINST ('$search_main' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 

    UNION

SELECT 
    'video' AS type,
    id,
    id AS id2,
    title,
    description,
    keywords,
    slug,
    date_original,
    date 
FROM cs_vlog 
WHERE MATCH(title,title,description,keywords,video_description) AGAINST ('$search_main' IN BOOLEAN MODE)


    UNION 

SELECT 
    'post' AS type,
    id,
    id AS id2,
    title, 
    description, 
    header, 
    slug, 
    date_original,
    date 
FROM cs_blog 
WHERE MATCH(title,title,description,keywords,header,body) AGAINST ('$search_main' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY date DESC
```

In other words, how can make all current posts first in the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every union part create a virtual column `expired`, then order your whole union by `order by expired asc, date desc`:

```
( select ..., expired from offer ... )
union all
( select ..., expire_date < now() as expired from sweep ...)
...
order by expired asc, date desc
```

Parentheses is important. Also make sure that the number and order of columns in every union part is the same.

Comment: Your answer is not clear. If one expires by 1 or 0 and the other expired by date - how do I compare results?

Comment: The answer is perfectly clear. As you can see, you simply convert expiration into a boolean by `expire_date < now() as expired`, so it's always `1` or `0`, `true` or `false`. It's simple and clean solution.

Comment: @DaedBaet, you convert it to the same 'format'. For example, if your table has a column `expired` that has `0` for active items and `1` for expired, you use it as is, thus `, expired ` in the select. And if you have an expire date for an item, you use the expression `expire_date < now()` that returns `1` when expire date is in the past and `0` if it isn't. To make it easier for you to track what expression means what you give it a name: `as expired`.